# How to forbid inserting in mysql if not match a regular expression?

Tags: mysql, regex

We know we can deal with regular expressions with mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE id REGEXP '5587$'
```

But what if I want some columns to be only have a specific regular expression, for example:

My table is something like that:

```
User MAC
MARK FE:4D:A2:F1:F2:F3
```

And the query is:

```
INSERT INTO table (User, MAC) VALUES (Mike,mark)
```

As we notice the query try to insert `mark`, which isn't a MAC address, How to forbid this situation or forbid any inserting that is not a MAC address?

Note: I'm using phpmyadmin to manage my DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you are using [INNOdb](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html), as no other storage engine supports constraits, you can add a [check constraint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html) looking something like:

```
CHECK(mac RLIKE '^([0-9A-F]{2}:){6}$')
```

Best of luck and if you need further assistance, do leave a comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try your suggestion